# How to redirect a client after a socket.io event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am building a simple login system using node.js and its socket.io module.
I am done with the authentication part, i.e., using MongoDB, I can now ascertain whether the user attempting to log in is genuine or fake.
At this stage, when I find a genuine login, I need to redirect the client to a different page (index.html). However, because a request is not sent and a response is not expected with a socket.io event, I cannot use
        response.setHeader(...);
because there is no 'response' parameter in my callback function. Here is my code:

On client side:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket=io();
    $('form').submit(function(){
        var un=$('#un').val();
        var pw=$('#pw').val();
        socket.emit('login',un,pw);
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

and on the server end,

```
var app=require('express')();
var server=require('http').Server(app);
var io=socket(server);
io.on('connection',function(client){
client.on('login',function(username,pw){
    //if authenticated, direct the client to index.html
    });
});
```

Can anyone please suggest any method to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way of accomplishing this is emitting a redirect event to your client, and handling the redirect on their end.

### Server-side:

```
var destination = '/index.html';
client.emit('redirect', destination);
```

### Client-side:

```
server.on('redirect', function(destination) {
    window.location.href = destination;
});
```

Comment: Yes, Max, I did this as the last resort to meet the demand. However, I thought that there had to be a more direct way, since redirection of client seems a pretty fundamental task.

Comment: I was looking for this as well, and what @kshubham07 was looking for is a way to redirect at http level, I assume. As I see this (I might be wrong), this isn't possible anymore once the session is established, e.g. after an event. It should be possible right after connect, though, if the library allows it. Can anybody weigh in?

Comment: well I thought there will be a `socket.redirect()` which would do the job.