# express js res.redirect undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Hello I am having a problem with redirecting with express js. I have a function that triggers when a submit button is pressed. At the very end of the function, I want it to redirect to a different page. 
When trying to use `res.redirect('/results.ejs');`, I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'redirect' of undefined`. Do I have to make res global or pass it to the function somehow?

`io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('query', function(qCity,qState,qLowPrice,qHighPrice){
    .....
    I want it to redirect here
    });//end of socket.on query function
});//end of io.on`

Thanks.

Comment: You don't have an HTTP request.  You need to tell your client JS to redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, you would need `res` to be in the same or higher scope of your `socket.on('query')`. So would want to "pass it to the function somehow."

Although that is not how this redirect should be handled. Because you are using a web socket you are going to want to redirect the user on the client when the socket on the server responds to the client. [Here is a Stack Overflow question on how that is done.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321792/how-to-redirect-a-client-after-a-socket-io-event)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm new to node and express and have been banging my head against this for like 3 days.