# Redirecting a page using socketio

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

i did these codes below and what i want to do is to send the redirecting data from pending.js to app.js after a condition is met, then send the redirecting page details to the html page. i am using app.js as like an middleware to send different kinds of details based on which condition is met.

pending.js (only showing one of the condition which emit the data to app.js)

```
if (req.body.data.status == "accept" && userIIDD == req.body.data.userId)
{
    console.log("accepted the data")
    ioCheck.on('connection', function(socket){
            console.log("connected v2")
            var destination = '/done'
            socket.emit('realDest', destination)
    })

}
```

there are 2 conditions, either accept or reject. when accepted, the destination of /done will be sent to the app.js and app.js will send to the client so it will know where to redirect.

app.js (only showing the socket io part)

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("really connected!");
    socket.on('realDest', function(destination){
        var route = destination;
        console.log(route);
    })
```

[trying to do something like this but i am adding for example: pending.js -> app.js -> html. because my app.js is to initialize the socket io connection so i wouldn't get any error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321792/how-to-redirect-a-client-after-a-socket-io-event)

Comment: both files pending.js and app.js are located on server side? If you are emitting from server then you should listen on client side instead of server side

Comment: Because i want to let app.js be like the middleware (initialize so the page wouldnt give any error) so that any communications with the client will pass thru app.js - suggested by my lecturer.

Comment: okay. then you should listen to event in web part not in app.js itself. Use socket in web and listen from web only.